# Detecting color not in color map created

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-imaging-library

I've got a problem detecting colors in an image. If I read all the pixels of the image, all colors detected are correct. I mean, I've got an image with 13 different colors and making the map color, there is no any other color detected except those 13 different colors.

The code which read all the pixels is:

```
def get_all_colors(self):
    sc = ShotColors()
    image = ShotChartImage(IMAGES.TEST_COLOUR_MAP)
    list_of_colors = sc.maristas_colors
    colors = {}
    for c in list_of_colors.keys():
        colors[c] = 0
    other_colors = {}
    errors = 0
    for y in range(image.image.height):
        for x in range(image.image.width):
            color = image.get_color(x, y)
            if color in list_of_colors:
                colors[color] = colors[color] + 1
            else:
                errors = errors + 1
                if color in other_colors:
                    other_colors[color] = other_colors[color] + 1
                else:
                    other_colors[color] = 1
    print(f"Colors matched: {colors}\n colors matched: {len(colors.keys())}")
    for k, v in sorted(colors.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print (k, v)
    print(f"Other colors: {other_colors})\ntotal other colors: {len(other_colors.keys())}")
    print(f"errors: {errors}")
```

The variable list_of_colors is a dictionary with these values:

```
self.maristas_colors = {
    "#C49812" : "C3R",
    "#704414" : "E3R",
    "#98817C" : "Ce3R",
    "#00E0EE" : "MBR",
    "#F40084" : "MER",
    "#00FF1E" : "PR",
    "#FF0000" : "PC",
    "#0054FF" : "PL",
    "#EEE600" : "MEL",
    "#7F4D68" : "MBL",
    "#036860" : "Ce3L",
    "#198D32" : "E3L",
    "#F8A9D4" : "C3L"
}
```

The image with I'm making the map color is:

[image]

And the result of making the map color is:

```
Colors matched: {'#C49812': 1119, '#704414': 5435, '#98817C': 20510, '#00E0EE': 6802,
                 '#F40084': 4854, '#00FF1E': 2912, '#FF0000': 2800, '#0054FF': 2912,
                 '#EEE600': 4805, '#7F4D68': 7458, '#036860': 20899, '#198D32': 7293,
                 '#F8A9D4': 1313}
 colors matched: 13

Other colors: {})
total other colors: 0
errors: 0
```

But, If I try to get the color of a determinated pixel, I have found that there are pixels with color is not in `self.maristas_colors` and always is the same color: `#000000` (black).

The code is:

```
def set_positions(self):
    '''Set the place in the field of each shoot'''
    sc = ShotColors()
    list_of_colors = sc.maristas_colors
    images = self.load_images()
    colors = {}
    for c in list_of_colors.keys():
        colors[c] = 0
    other_colors = {}
    self.errors = 0
    for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
        image = self.select_image(images, row["team"])
        color = image.get_color(row["x"], row["y"])
        if color in list_of_colors:
            self.df.at[index, "position"] = list_of_colors[color]
            colors[color] = colors[color] + 1
        else:
            self.errors = self.errors + 1
            if color in other_colors:
                other_colors[color] = other_colors[color] + 1
            else:
                other_colors[color] = 1
    print(f"colors: {colors}\n total_colors: {len(colors.keys())}")
    print(f"other colors: {other_colors}\n total other colors: {len(other_colors.keys())}")
    print(f"errores: {self.errors}")
```

And the result of trying to detect the color of some pixels with this code is:

```
colors: {'#C49812': 1, '#704414': 5, '#98817C': 13, '#00E0EE': 198, '#F40084': 120,
         '#00FF1E': 225, '#FF0000': 331, '#0054FF': 203, '#EEE600': 94, '#7F4D68': 265,
         '#036860': 37, '#198D32': 21, '#F8A9D4': 12}
 total_colors: 13

other colors: {'#000000': 21}
 total other colors: 1
```

How is that possible? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit I:**

I have found the problem. Before to get the color from a pixel I rotate the image. If I remove this rotation then the color I get is correct.

How Is it possible? How is possible to get black color always from a pixel after rotating the image?

Comment: You're close to having one, but you need to provide a _runnable_ [mre].

Comment: Is there any website like CodeSandBox for python?

Comment: What is `ShotColors`? `ShotChartImage`? Why have you removed all your `import` statements so no-one knows what packages you are using?

Comment: ShotColors is a class with colors and ShotChartImage load the image that I want to read. But, it doesn't matter this classe. I have edit my initial post with the reason why I've got black color from a pixel.